# How to use cycle?

Tags: php

Please help me

I don't understand at all how I need to use cycle for `$data`. As I understand it, it must be sorted out using a loop, but how?

```
public function handle()
    {
        $redmineService = new RedmineAPIService();
        $users = $redmineService->getUsersInfo();


        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $data = $redmineService->getTimeEntriesInfo($user['id']);
            foreach ($data as $datum) {
                $id = $datum['id'];
                $project = $datum['project'];
                $activity = $datum['activity'];
                $issue = $datum['issue'];
                $comments = $datum['comments'];

                if ($this->confirm('Is this information correct?')) {
                    $link = new TimeEntry();
                    $link->id = $id;
                    $link->project = $project;
                    $link->activity = $activity;
                    $link->issue = $issue;
                    $link->comments = $comments;
                    //dd($link->getAttributes());
                    $link->save();
            }

                $this->info("Saved.");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**dd($link->getAttributes());**

```
249 => array:10 [
    "id" => 5369
    "project" => array:2 [ …2]
    "issue" => array:1 [ …1]
    "user" => array:2 [ …2]
    "activity" => array:2 [ …2]
    "hours" => 1.0
    "comments" => "Comment"
    "spent_on" => "2022-05-27"
    "created_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
    "updated_on" => "2022-05-27T05:00:19Z"
  ]
```

**UPD**
Now I have mistake `Undefined array key "id"` `➜  50▕             $id = $data['id'];`

Comment: Check ```UPD```

Comment: As I understand I need to iterate over the array

Comment: I changed ```handle()```(check above) but I have ```Undefined array key "id"```

Comment: Now I just delete ```id```. But then I have ```Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given``` for ```comments```